# Make a SELECT query from two tables with one record from matching rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I do have two mysql tables named `Services` and `Images`. Each service may have multiple images.

So my question is, just I need to make a `SELECT` query to get all services with one image to each service.

This is how I tried it. But it gave me all services and all images to each service.

```
SELECT s.id
        , s.name
        , s.description
        , i.id as image_id
        , i.image
FROM  services s
LEFT JOIN images i ON i.service_id = s.id;
```

Can anybody tell me how I make this query correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: which one? (this is starting to sound like the most frequently asked question under the mysql tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you need just one image for one service you can `group by` your `service id`

```
SELECT s.id
        , s.name
        , s.description
        , i.id as image_id
        , i.image
FROM  services s
LEFT JOIN images i ON i.service_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to get all services that have only one image:

```
SELECT s.id
        , s.name
        , s.description
        , i.id as image_id
        , i.image
FROM  services s
JOIN images i on i.service_id = s.id
WHERE i.service_id in (
  SELECT service_id FROM images GROUP BY service_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Comment: @user3733831 It works for me, but it depends on what exactly you are looking for. This will create a list of all services that have exactly one associated image. If you are looking for something else, you might clarify it in your question.